# File doesn't store

Tags: php, laravel

While file uploading I have directories created, no errors, but pictures don't store; I see only empty folders.

I know there is something stupid that I am missing, but I can't see what exactly

**Controller.php**

```
 if($request->hasFile('picture')){
     //Create a directory if doesn't exist
     $dir = 'storage/images/students/'.$campus.'/'.$program.'/'.$group.'/';
     if (!File::isDirectory(public_path($dir))){
             File::makeDirectory(public_path($dir), 0775, true, true);}

     $path       = 'images/students/'.$campus.'/'.$program.'/'.$group;
     $picture    = $request->file('picture');
     $filename   = $request->id.'.'.$picture->getClientOriginalExtension();

     $public_path = $request->file('picture')->storeAs($path, $filename,'public');
 }
```

**filesystem.php**

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

[Documentation page](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-uploads)

Comment: Why are you creating a directory using `public_path()` (if it doesn't exist) but then you're storing the image under your `storage` directory (`storage_path()`)?

Comment: @Rwd thanks for your comment. However, I am not sure what you're asking... do you mean that method  `storeAs()` stores images as if I used `storage_path()`.

Comment: The `if` statement is checking for a directory `public_path('storage/images/...')`, however, when your using `storeAs` your specifying that the file should be saved in the `public` disk which according to your `config/filesystem.php` is using `storage_path('app/public')`. Have you checked to see if the file exists at `ROOT_OF_PROJECT/storage/app/public/images/students/...`?

Answer (score 0):

Little Improvement, Quite sure it will work

```
if($request->hasFile('picture')){

     $path = 'images/students/'.$campus.'/'.$program.'/'.$group.'/';

     //Create a directory if doesn't exist
     if (!Storage::disk('public')->exists($path)){
             File::makeDirectory(public_path($path), 0775, true, true);}


     $picture    = $request->file('picture');
     $filename   = $request->hanson_id.'.'.$picture->getClientOriginalExtension();

     $public_path = Storage::disk('public')->put( $filename, $request->file('picture'));
 }
```

If you want to go with your own code You missed to write **Storage**

```
if($request->hasFile('picture')){
 //Create a directory if doesn't exist
 $dir = 'storage/images/students/'.$campus.'/'.$program.'/'.$group.'/';
 if (!File::isDirectory(public_path($dir))){
         File::makeDirectory(public_path($dir), 0775, true, true);}

 $path       = 'images/students/'.$campus.'/'.$program.'/'.$group;
 $picture    = $request->file('picture');
 $filename   = $request->hanson_id.'.'.$picture->getClientOriginalExtension();

 $public_path = Storage::disk('public')->put( $filename, $request->file('picture'));
```

}

Comment: Got an error : `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter::put(), 1 passed and at least 2 expected`

Comment: @VirtualDevice updated answer, Forgot to remove saveAs from your snippet

Answer (score 0):

Update your filesystem's config and controller code as below

**filesystem.php**

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads',
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
    'visibility' => 'public',
]
```

**Controller.php**

```
if($request->hasFile('picture')){
    //Create a directory if doesn't exist
    $dir = 'storage/images/students/'.$campus.'/'.$program.'/'.$group;
    if (!File::isDirectory(public_path($dir))) {
        File::makeDirectory(public_path($dir), 0775, true, true);
    }
    $picture    = $request->file('picture');
    $filepath   = $dir . '/' . $request->hanson_id.'.'.$picture->getClientOriginalExtension();

    return Storage::disk('public')->put($filepath, $picture));
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you can pass a path to `public_path()` rather than concatenate it on so `public_path() . '/uploads'` can also be written as `public_path('uploads')'`.